# Sromku facebook login issue

Tags: android, facebook, android-simple-facebook

I'm trying to use SimpleFacebook SDK to log in and share something on my wall, but seems that is not possible because I get this in the logCat:

```
09-11 16:08:30.836: E/ActivityThread(12092): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
09-11 16:08:30.876: E/com.facebook.LoginActivity(12092): Cannot call LoginActivity with a null calling package. This can occur if the launchMode of the caller is singleInstance.
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.masterdetailsexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.masterdetailsexample.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.masterdetailsexample.CircleListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.masterdetailsexample.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.masterdetailsexample.Details"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.masterdetailsexample.TestSearch"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.masterdetailsexample.FavoritesActivity"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.masterdetailsexample.Overlay"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.masterdetailsexample.FullScreenBanner"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.masterdetailsexample.DevicesIntro"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.masterdetailsexample.CircleDetailActivity"
            android:label="Circle detail" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".CircleListActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!--
        <receiver android:name="com.example.masterdetailsexample.NetworkStateReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Does anyone knows what is the issue here?

Comment: there are some reason for this . incorrect App id ,incorrect  Hash key. If you are checking in device please check your facebook app installed on Android is not outdated and  consistent with  Facebook Android SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check hashkey for fb app and app id in manifest

1. Open https://developers.facebook.com/
2. Register as developer
3. Add new app
4. Open **Dashboard**, where you can find **App ID**
5. Add **App ID** in your AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
           android:value="**App ID**"
       />
   ```
6. Open **Settings** and Add your email
7. Add platform **+ Add Platform** and choose **Android**
8. Add your **package name** from your AndroidManifest.xml
9. For hash key use 'keytool':

   keytool -exportcert -alias  -keystore  | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Or programmatically:

```
public void printHashKey() {
   try {
      PackageInfo info = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.gorbin.androidsocialnetworksextended.asne",
      PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
      for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
         MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
         md.update(signature.toByteArray());
         Log.d("HASH KEY:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
      }
   } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
   }
   }
```

11. Open **Status & Review** and start app

More detailed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: how should I do that?

Comment: @DarkoPetkovski write small tutorial